# Is there a way to make a Mac wake on network activity?

Tags: macos

I've got a Mac that's connected to a router (wired ethernet).

I'm running a server software on the Mac.

Ideally, I'd like to put it to sleep and have it wake up when there's an activity on the network line (i.e. a client trying to connect to the server).

In Preferences, I've gone to Energy Preferences and enabled 'wake on network' option.

Not working.

I'm just testing within the same network.

Comment: This page might help, I don't know what type of Mac you have, or how old it is http://kb.netop.com/article/wake-on-lan-for-macos-449.html

Comment: Does it react to [wake on LAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wake-on-LAN#Magic_packet) packets when "wake on network" is enabled? If yes, configure the router to send such packets when the router detects the kind of activitiy that should wake up the Mac. If necessary, install OpenWRT etc. on the router.